# Restrict file access to append only

Tags: linux, permissions, logs, rsync, xfs

I have a directory with log files and I'm putting
logs from script launched by users into them. Logging with syslog doesn't seem
possible in this case. (non-daemon rsync)

I want the users to have only write permissions on log files.
The problem is, that write permissions must be further restricted, so that 
users (script) can **only append** to that files.
The underlying filesystem is XFS.

The following doesn't work:

```
# chattr +a test.log
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on test.log
```

Is there any other solution for this? Thank you for your hints.

Comment: Are you sure it's XFS? `chattr +a` works for me here (3.2 kernel). Note that you need to be root to use `chattr` (a `$` prompt suggests non-superuser), though you'd get a different error message if `chattr +a` was supported and you were not root.

Comment: [Also posted on Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/461786/restrict-file-access-to-append-only). [Don't do this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073)

Comment: What is the mount options on the partition? It might possibly store it using xattr, which might need the relevant mount option? (The socumentation for XFS don't mention much about it either...)

Comment: This closed on SF, so I'm leaving it open here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `chattr` utility is written for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems. It emits [ioctls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) on the files, so it's up to the underlying filesystem to decide what to do with them. The XFS driver in newer Linux kernels supports the same `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` ioctl as ext[234] to control flags such as append-only, but you may be running an older kernel where it doesn't (CentOS?). Try using the [`xfs_io`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_io) utility instead:

```
echo chattr +a | xfs_io test.log
```

Note that, for XFS like for ext[234], only root can change the append-only flag (more precisely, you need the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permissions to do that? From `man 1 chattr`:

> A file with the `a' attribute set can only be open in append  mode  for  writing. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can achieve the same using **SELinux**, chances are it's enabled and running if you are using Red Hat compatible distro. This works on every filesystem, SELinux blocks processes from performing disallowed operations.

Unfortunately, you need to write a policy for your application to allow accessing all system resources, except appending to particular file(s). This can be challenging a bit if you do this for the fist time, but there is an advantage to this - added layer of security.

I have an example of how to write a append-only file rule in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQcYXJkwTns